# How can I fix the input and index operator overloading problem?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to implement index and input operator overloading ([] and >>) in C++ language. The program should ask user to input an integer then it should print digits of this integer, but my program does not works correctly. I cannot understand where the problem is. How can I fix the problem? Thanks in advance for your helps.

**The output that my program gives:**

```
Default constructor of Integer class
Enter a 4 digits number: 6748
0th digit of the number: 6748
1st digit of the number: -858993460
2nd digit of the number: -858993460
3rd digit of the number : -858993460
Destructor of Integer class
Destructor of Integer class
```

**The output that I want:**

```
Default constructor of Integer class
Enter a 4 digits number: 6748
0th digit of the number: 8
1st digit of the number: 4
2nd digit of the number: 7
3rd digit of the number : 6
Destructor of Integer class
Destructor of Integer class
```

**My Integer.h class:**

```
#include <iostream>
#pragma once
#ifndef INTEGER_H
#define INTEGER_H
#define size 4
using namespace std;

class Integer {
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& inp, Integer& obj); // >> operator overloading
private:
    int r, i;
    int ptr[size];

public:
    //Integer(); //default constructor
    Integer();
    Integer(int*);
    ~Integer(); //destructor

    int& operator[](int index);  //[] operator overloading
};
#endif // !INTEGER_H
```

**Integer.cpp**

```
#include "Integer.h"
Integer::Integer() {
    cout << "Default constructor of Integer class" << endl;
}
Integer::~Integer() {
    cout << "Destructor of Integer class" << endl;
}

Integer::Integer(int* p) {
    //n = ptr;
    if(size!=0){
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            //memcpy(p, ptr, 4 * sizeof(int));
            p = ptr;
            //ptr[i] = p[i];
            //ptr[i]=p[i];
    }

    }
}
istream& operator >> (istream& inp, Integer &obj) {
    inp >> obj.ptr[size-1];
    return inp;

}

int& Integer::operator[](int index) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < size) {
        return ptr[index];
    }
    /*if (index >= size && size<0) {
        cout << "Wrong size!" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    return ptr[index];*/
}
```

**Main.cpp program:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Integer.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Integer a;


    cout << "Enter a 4 digits number: ";
    cin >> a;
    Integer a1(a);
        cout << "0th digit of the number: " << a[3] << endl;
        cout << "1st digit of the number: " << a[2] << endl;
        cout << "2nd digit of the number: " << a[1] << endl;
        cout << "3rd digit of the number : " << a[0] << endl;



    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The `Integer(int* p)` constructor has a major bug but I don't yet know if that's the source of your experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your code.
In your input function:

```
istream& operator >> (istream& inp, Integer &obj) {
    inp >> obj.ptr[size-1];
    return inp;

}
```

1. What actually happens, when you enter `1234`, is that you're storing it entirely in `obj.ptr[size - 1]`. You should slice up each digit and store it in a seperate index.
2. You're always storing your input number in `ptr[size - 1]`, which is always the last element in your array. If you want to slice your number, you should increment/decrement the index you're modifying the array at.

If I were you, I would probably do it similar to:

```
istream& operator >> (istream& inp, Integer &obj) {
    int input;
    inp >> input;
    while(sizePtr >= 0) {
        obj.ptr[sizePtr--] = input % 10;
        input /= 10;
    }
    return inp;
}
```

Where `sizePtr` is a non-const variable as the size (-1 for zero indexing) of your `ptr` object array.

Comment: while condition may cause problem if the input value is 0010.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't think of leading zeros

Comment: The OP is ifxed to 4 digits, so it is better to run 4 times decomposition. The zeros do no harm.